Debugging c# Blazor W3WP worker process via DotNetSpyEx - Modules don't show up
I'm attempting to debug the IIS worker process via DotNetSpy(ex) however the modules aren't showing.
Below is what shows up in the debugger vs what shows up under the modules tab of ProcessHacker.

Anyone seen this behaviour before?
Possible interference by antivirus or something? How can I determine this?


